# ¿Cómo hacer 2 consultas SQL en 1 sola con 2 tablas?

Tags: sql

Tengo un inconveniente con esta consulta en SQL:

Tengo 2 tablas (Asesores.dbf    Usuarios.dbf)

Resulta que necesito hacer un conteo de registros de 2 columnas distintas de la misma tabla Asesores.dbf bajo ciertos condicionamientos, mismos que expongo a continuación:

CONSULTA 1.

```
select B.nombre AS ASESOR, count(A.estado) as PRINCIPALES, FECHA_CALL = GETDATE ()
FROM ASESORES A, Usuarios B
WHERE A.fecha >= '2019-03-19T00:00:00.000' and A.estado = 'ACEPTA' AND   A.operador = B.login 
group by B.nombre
order by B.nombre
```

CONSULTA 2.

```
SELECT B.nombre AS ASESOR, COUNT(A.cedula_adicional_1) AS ADICIONALES
FROM ASESORES A, Usuarios B
WHERE A.fecha >= '2019-03-19T00:00:00.000' and (A.tipo_documento_adicional_1 like '%CED%' OR A.tipo_documento_adicional_1 like '%PAS%' OR A.tipo_documento_adicional_1 like '%RUC%') and A.operador = B.login
group by B.nombre order by B.nombre
```

El problema es que necesito hacer lo mismo en una sola consulta y no se cómo hacerlo, por favor su cordial ayuda, gracias.

Resultado deseado:

```
ASESOR    PRINCIPALES     ADICIONALES      FECHA_CALL
```

Comment: ¿qué base de datos utilizas?

Comment: ¿Hay algún motivo por el que no puedas combinar los `where` faltantes de la segunda consulta con la primera? Ambas son casi identicas

Comment: ¡Hola @FranciscoGarrido! Parece que quiere distintos resultados en cada columna, por eso lo he resuelto con un JOIN. Qué bueno verte por las consultas de SQL... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asumiendo que las quieres juntar en horizontal, utilizando el SQL más estándar posible (porque no indicas el sistema gestor que utilizas), y arriesgándome a publicarla sin probarla porque, enviar el SQL de los datos de muestra, a todos os parece algo opcional (de verdad que ya no sé qué hacer para que lo publiquéis en la pregunta), te propongo la siguiente solución:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT B.nombre AS ASESOR, count(A.estado) as PRINCIPALES,
        FECHA_CALL = GETDATE ()
      FROM ASESORES A, Usuarios B
        WHERE A.fecha >= '2019-03-19T00:00:00.000' and A.estado = 'ACEPTA' 
        AND   A.operador = B.login
        group by B.nombre
  ) c1 LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT B.nombre AS ASESOR, COUNT(A.cedula_adicional_1) AS ADICIONALES
      FROM ASESORES A, Usuarios B
        WHERE A.fecha >= '2019-03-19T00:00:00.000' and 
          (A.tipo_documento_adicional_1 like '%CED%' OR 
          A.tipo_documento_adicional_1 like '%PAS%' OR 
          A.tipo_documento_adicional_1 like '%RUC%') and A.operador = B.login
        group by B.nombre  
  ) c2 ON c1.ASESOR=c2.ASESOR
  ORDER by ASESOR;
```

Simplemente he hecho un JOIN utilizando dos subconsultas:

```
SELECT * FROM () c1 LEFT JOIN () c2 
  ON c1.ASESOR=c2.ASESOR
  ORDER by ASESOR;
```

Fíjate que he metido tus consultas en cada uno de los paréntesis que ahora he dejado en blanco.

Pruébalo y me dices

Comment: David, agradezco mucho tu ayuda... me ha servido de maravilla.. lo único que no me funcionaba era la última línea ORDER BY ASESOR, la corregí con ORDER BY c1.ASESOR...

Comment: Claro, estaría dándote ambigüedad porque no sabría si sacar ASESOR de c1 o c2, cuando curiosamente tienen que coincidir... ¡bien resuelto! Me alegra que te haya servido

Comment: David, te molesto con otro inconveniente respecto al mismo tema, resulta que la instrucción puesta me arroja el resultado correcto, pero no de todos los usuarios, algunos usuarios no tienen Ventas Adicionales, o sea no han realizado Ventas Adicionales, pero si, Ventas Principales, como puedo hacer para que me arroje un resultado de 0 o en blanco, si es que no tienen Ventas Adicionales???.. Claro en la columna de ADICIONALES se reflejaría este 0 o en blanco, cabe recalcar que siempre van a existir ventas Principales y no siempre Ventas Adicionales… por tu gentil ayuda agradezco de antemano.

Comment: Pues precisamente lo acabo de ver en la solución que tenía preparada @FranciscoGarrido para tí, ya tienes la modificación hecha. Con LEFT JOIN aparecerán todos los registros de c1 aunque no estén en c2

Comment: @ FranciscoGarrido y David... les agradezco por su gentil ayuda.. me ha servido mucho...